# At the end of WWII, were Nazis working on any other super weapon besides V-2?

Tags: world-war-two, military, nazi-germany, weapons

At the end of WWII, were Nazis working on anything else besides the V-2? If so, what was it, how close was it to completion, and could it have potentially turn the events around for them?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60453/discussion-on-question-by-eugene-at-the-end-of-wwii-were-nazis-working-on-any-o).

Comment: Doesn't anyone watch the History Channel? Isn't nazi superweapons one of their mainstays?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Wunderwaffe (literally, wonder weapons) - absolutely, they had many, many designs under way.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wunderwaffe

They were working on the A9/A10 (imagine it as an evolution of the V1/V2 series of rockets), that would be a multi-stage ICBM that would be able to hit the US, although it wasn't likely to be very accurate.  This was planned to be available from 1946.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_series#A9

The Nazi's had already tested firing V2s from submarines, the plan here was to allow them to launch at the mainland US from U-boats just off the coast of the US.  They had actually manufactured three of the required launchers to do this and had conducted extensive tests by the end of the war.

http://www.prinzeugen.com/V2.htm

No doubt you have already heard about the Amerika Bomber, there were several candidates under various stages of development.  Hitler had a fascination with bombers and so this was one area of development that got a lot of funding, at the expense of other, arguably more important schemes:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amerika_Bomber

There were several "super heavy tank" designs being planned, with the Maus being most advanced, they actually had built two prototypes of this by the end of the war.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panzer_VIII_Maus

However, the Maus is nothing compared to these behemoths!

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landkreuzer_P._1000_Ratte

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landkreuzer_P._1500_Monster

The above were only at the fairly early stages of planning.

There were plans for a super-heavy battleship, the H Class that would be around 140,000 tons with 20 inch guns that would dwarf the Yamato, two keels were laid down but soon scrapped.

There were many other plans, guided missiles, super-guns, helicopters to name a few, it's a very interesting subject with plenty of information on the internet.

There are other more conspiracy theory types of weapons that I won't go into here, but if you search for Hitlers Bell (Die Glocke) you'll find one example.

Comment: Most of these designs were utter lunacy.

Comment: and some were brilliant, had they only had the materials to produce them...

Comment: @davidjwest What about the lost ark of the covenant? You forgot about that one.

Comment: the towed Lafferentz capsules which I think you refer to were imaginative but relatively impractical. They consumed all of the fuel of a long range type IX-D2 U-boat in a one way voyage to the American Atlantic seaboard. One 500 ton capsule was tested in trials with U-1062 (IIRC) and was never found after the war whilst three improved 800 ton capsules were found at the Vulcan Stettner shipyards by the Soviets. these became the basis for all modern ballistic missile submarines. The biggest drawback was decomposition of hydrogen peroxide required to drive V-2 fuel turbopumps.

Comment: The He-274 was the intended Amerika bomber, but sabotage by french workers held up progress. Late in the war there was a proposal to re-wing He-177 aircraft in Norway with the same wing developed for the Me-264. There was an aircraft factory in Oslo there performing sub-contract work to Messerschmitt.

Comment: The Nazi Bell was a particle accelerator rather than a weapon, although two variations of the nazi bell design were adapted as so called "death ray" particle beam weapons, one at Gross Ostheim air base south of Franfurt used against bomber formations to disable their engines.. One of these particle beam weapons was recovered from the ruins of Dresden by Dr Rolf Wideroe and transported southwest to Berggrub where Patton's Army captured it on 14 March 1945. The united states tested and replicated these devices under "Project Seesaw"

Comment: I would add that the cult of the Wunderwaffe (typical of the Nazi mentality) was the cause (or an acceleration) of the German defeat, particularly on the East. For example, a Panther tank (design partly inspired from the T-34) could easily knock out 5 or 6 T-34 in a battle before getting hit. But at Kursk, the Russians had 17 T-34 ready for each Panther tank because it was incredibly faster and cheaper to assemble. Similarly, a Tiger tank usually had a mechanical problem every 10 km.

Comment: @Yves: It was not a "cult", it was a necessity. Even if Germany had *designed* a tank capable of mass production at the same rates as the T-34 or the M4 Sherman, they would not have the resources to build them, not the fuel to get them moving, and not the men to crew them. And even then they'd be outnumbered against the Russians. What Germany was looking for were weapon systems capable of beating the odds. They could not counter quantity with quantity, they had to counter with quality. That's why German initial planning didn't look beyond 41/42, as that was their "window of opportunity".

Comment: @DevSolar not sure about that, I'll look into the figures. I remember that the production and reliability of German jets was limited by nickel and molybdenum availability, which were however not so crucial for tank design. On the other side the Wunderwaffe was an integral part of the Endsieg belief and from 1943 on the Total War ideology. And I believe the Germans started strategic planning only when it became clear that their "window" (1940 on the western front, 1941 on the eastern) was vanishing.

Answer (score 12):

German physicist tried to build an atomic bomb, at least there were experiments.

At end of WW2 there was a  laboratory in [Haigerloch](http://www.haigerloch.de/stadt/atomkeller.html). It is told, that American scientist checked everything and took the Uranium (and the German scientists) to the US. If the German scientists really tried to build an atomic bomb is not really clear.

More can be found in [Physics Today - Volume 53, Issue 7, Page 34. "The German Uranium Project"](http://www.physicstoday.org/resource/1/phtoad/v53/i7)

---

Another (more popular) article. I added a rough translation.

[Stern magazine: Der Atomkeller von Haigerloch](http://www.stern.de/wissen/natur/forschung/deutsche-kernforschung-der-atomkeller-von-haigerloch-543887.html)  (Sorry German)

> In britischer Gefangenschaft können es die Wissenschaftler später kaum fassen, als sie am Abend des 6. August von der US-Zündung einer Atombombe über der japanischen Stadt Hiroshima hören.

The German scientiste were astonished, when the heard about the exposion of the US-bomb in Hiroshima

> Die Forscher um Heisenberg behaupteten nur eine "Uran-Kraftmaschine" entwickeln zu wollen. "Die Atombombe stand nicht auf dem Programm", betonte der beteiligte Wirtz nach dem Krieg. Neuere Forschungen ergaben jedoch Hinweise auf eine vorhandene gezielte deutsche Atombombenforschung.

The sientist say, they only wanted to build a "power machine". But newer researches give an indication of plans to build atomic bomb.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info! Extra plus is a non-Wikipedia source, but I can only +1 once :)

Comment: I'd read elsewhere that the captured records at the end of the war stated that the Germans had worked on it for a while, decided it was impossible, and had quit. Wish I could find that reference.

Comment: The German's were well ahead of the US in the development of an atomic weapon in the late 1930's but due to cutbacks in research they fell behind.  Germany cut back on a lot of research projects around 1940 as the war was going so well only to begin re-investing when things started to go badly around the 1942/1943.  Lucky for us they did scale back research for at least a couple of years!  http://www.yourdiscovery.com/web/world-war-2/ww2-focus/flashpoints/atomic-bomb/

Comment: @davidjwest: The Nazis lost the atomic race when they chased away Einstein, who started the U.S. atomic effort instead. They would have gotten the atomic bomb if he had been working on a GERMAN bomb. See my answer below.

Comment: @TomAu - My understanding was that Einstein's main contribution to the building of the A-bombs was convincing the US Government to create them. He didn't actually work on them. However, a lot of physicists did, and there were certianly German and Eastern European refugees among them. So the point is a good one, if you expand it to scientists in general.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Einstein didn't do the "grunt work" on buildng the bomb. But he 1) practically founded the field of atomic physics, paving the way for later contributions by others, and 2) convinced FDR in face-to-face meetings to build an American bomb. (Few, if any other scientists had the prestige to do this.) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein If he had been working on the German side, he would have corrected Heisenberg's (mis) calculations, and the rest would have been history (see below).

Comment: Clearly the contributers here are unaware of the work of Harteck developing the ultracentrifuge or Martin & Khun developing the Zippe centrifuge which USA had no equivalent to. Manhattan scientists Jessie Beams tried and failed during WW2 to develop a Uranium centrifuge which was far superior to US porous barrier methods or the CALTRON. Beams was unable to develop a US centrifuge until well after the war with the benefit of captured Nazi patents.

Comment: You are confusing the reaction of Heisenberg and the civilian KWG scientists at Farm Hall with the reaction of Kurt Diebner, head of German Army Ordnance's Atomic bomb project the only scientist present at Farm Hall actually involved in the german A-bomb project whose lips remained silent. Diebner was actually overheard prior to 6th August warning Heisenberg to be careful what he said because the British had bugged them with hidden microphones. After this warning Heisenberg began to sing like a canary for the microphones.

Comment: Popp 2016: "Misinterpreted Documents and Ignored Physical Facts: The History of ‘Hitler's Atomic Bomb’ needs to be corrected" (http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/bewi.201601794/abstract) shows that the German physicist did not know how to build a nuclear bomb.

Comment: Einstein's contribution to the atomic project was his stature - only a letter from him to Roosevelt could have initiated the action that it did.

Answer (score 7):

The nearest and biggest threat to the allies, had it made it into combat, was the Horten Ho-229 flying wing fighter, and the 6 engine heavy bomber that was being designed for bombing campaigns against the American east coast.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horten_Ho_229
Had it made it into production in numbers, it could have changed the balance of power in the air. Of course on its own it would likely not have changed the outcome of the war, it was far too late for that.

Comment: Given that German jet engines typically had a TBO life of just 25 hours it is hard to imagine how a six engine Gotha bomber could count on all six engines to work for the entire flight?

Comment: @user2357 that was a problem more with the manufacturing than the design. As we're in the realm of speculation as to what might have been, we can speculate they could have manufactured higher quality goods as well.

Comment: @user2357: That German jet engines had such short lifespan was mostly due to the lack of alloy materials -- chrome, nickel etc. -- required to make high-quality steel. They knew how, they just lacked the material. (Same goes for the infamous Panther transmission by the way.) For any of the "Luftwaffe '46" projects to come to fruitition, the tides of war would have had to be more in Germany's favor. Perhaps a couple of merchant ships making it through blockade, or holding on to some of those mines in the east for a bit longer?

Comment: @DevSolar and manufacturing at the end being mostly done by unskilled and unmotivated slave labour rather than skilled and well paid citizens. It's not known how many V2s and other late war German weapons failed due to manufacturing defects that were introduced either deliberately or through carelessness by the slave labourers in German factories and never caught due to lack of quality control, but it's thought to be substantial.

Comment: @jwenting: That's a different subject, really. The Jumo 004 was produced at the Junkers works in Magdeburg; I am not sure how much slave labor was involved there. And the Panther drive was a much simplified design as the originally intended planetary gear could not be produced in the numbers required. I do not say that slave labor / sabotage wasn't a thing, but it did impact specific products (like the V2 assembly in Mittelbau-Dora), it did not apply across the board.

Comment: @DevSolar possibly, but it certainly was a factor in jet production (the Me262 was for example).

Comment: Since the 229 never made it out of a prototype stage with only a few test flights, comments on its effectiveness are highly speculative. As the US learned with the B35/B49 flying wing, flight control technology of the time just wasn't up to the demands of a flying wing. Both the UK and US had jet fighters in an early stage, in the Gloster Meteor and Lockheed P80 that could have posed a serious threat to any German jet fighter, and they would have been built in far greater numbers. And... the only reason the US didn't employ nuclear weapons against Germany was - the war ended first.

Comment: @tj1000 as this question is about weapons under development that could have posed a threat, the 229 is certainly relevant to the question

Answer (score 6):

It depends on what you see as a super-weapon.

In the fighter aircraft arena, by the end of the war Germany already had the [Me 262](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messerschmitt_Me_262) twin engine jet fighter and the [Me 163](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messerschmitt_Me_163) rocket powered fighter in service. It must be said that the Me 163 was not particularly effective.

The need to improve on the Me 163 led to development of the [Me 263](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messerschmitt_Me_263) rocket fighter, along with the [Ju 248](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messerschmitt_Me_263#Ju_248).

More advanced jet powered designs were built, including the [Messerschmitt P.1101](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messerschmitt_Me_P.1101) variable sweep jet fighter, and the [Focke-Wulf Ta 183](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focke-Wulf_Ta_183) transonic fighter.

Another advanced desiagn was the [Lippisch P.13a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lippisch_P.13a) ramjet delta wing interceptor, which never got off the drawing board.

None of these reached production.

Comment: In addition, the [Arado AR-234 was the world's first operational jet bomber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arado_Ar_234). It never was produced in large numbers, but this, along with the rest of the Germans' jet technology, was without doubt a formidable advance.

Answer (score 5):

The Germans were working on an atomic bomb. But the effort was stymied for a couple reaons.

1. The effort was led by Werner Heisenberg (of the Heisenberg uncertainty principle), who had a less-than-perfect understanding of atomic physics. (And the Nazis had chased away the better, "Jewish" atomic scientists like Einstein and Fermi.) Some say that Heisenberg was a "bungler." But his defenders would say that he sabotaged the German atomic effort. For instance, he went to his former professor (Niels Bohr, a Danish Jew living in Copenhagen) for answers to his questions about atomic physics, and failed to get them. The Gestapo offered to torture the answers out of Bohr, but Heisenberg declined.
2. The Germans had a shortage of "[heavy water](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavy_water)", most of which was produced in Norway. On one occasion, Allied agents planted a time bomb to blow up a ship transported a load of "heavy water" from Norway to Germany. Finally, Allied saboteurs blew up the producing Norwegian hydroelectric plant itself.

Comment: Actually, Fermi wasn't Jewish. But his WIFE was. And that was (bad) "enough" for the Nazis to have him ostracized in the European atomic world.

Comment: Wow. Can you dig up links for any of this? I'd love to read more.

Comment: @T.E.D., Richard Rhodes wrote 2 books on the history of atomic weapons (The History of the Atomic Bomb, and Dark Sun) which go into more detail than you probably want. Heisenburg miscalculated the "mean free path" (the average distance a neutron can travel before colliding with a nucleus), and according to his calculations about all the U-235 in the world was needed to make a single atom bomb. Because of his status, no one would question his calculations.

Comment: @T.E.D. Here's a link to wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werner_Heisenberg. I remember seeing the "Niels Bohr" play about 20 years ago, and got it from there, not a book. Now you see why I believe that Heisenberg (a Nobel Prize winnter), "knew what he was doing." What he did't know, he didn't want to know.

Comment: Well, even geniuses can make honest mistakes. However, I like the idea of him doing it on purpose much better, so I'm happy to leave it at that until told otherwise. :-)

Comment: @T.E.D.: Heisenberg, Fermi, and America's Robert Oppenheimer were about the same age; Einstein and Bohr were of "mentor" age. Of the world's five best atomic scientists, three worked for the U.S. (Einstein, Fermi, and Oppenheimer), one (Bohr) was "neutral" (until 1943 when he escaped to England) and one Heisenberg was "questionable." Key line from another site http://www.financialsensearchive.com/editorials/au/2006/0509.html "The persecution of Jewish scientists like Einstein, Fermi and Bohr tipped the balance in the Allies' favor."

Comment: Heavy water is not H2O2 (this is Hydrogen peroxide) but H2O being the Hydrogen atoms an isotope (Deuterium) that has one proton and one neutron instead the usual hydrogen atom that onlye have one proton.

Comment: Harteck disclosed after the war that the Germans knew of the attack on the Hydro ferry in advance and allowed the shipment to go ahead, whilst the bulk of a 6.5 tonne shipment made it from Norway to Dr Karl Wirtz's laboratory in Silesia six weeks after the Hydro was sunk.

Comment: Averroes it is not H2O either. It is D20 = Deuterium Oxide

Comment: Nazi Germany was not solely reliant on the Vermork plant in Norway. There was a sister plant at Saheim and a similar Montecanteni Plant in the Italian Alps. The Germans also had the Linde plant near Munich, the IG Farben Leuna plant at Mersberg, the Geib Sulfide plant near Kiel. The Nazis were swimming in Deuterium by late 1944, but allowed the Allies and even their own people to believe the Hydro sinking had ended their chances to mislead their enemy and conceal that the nuclear project was still in progress.

Comment: Popp 2016: "Misinterpreted Documents and Ignored Physical Facts: The History of ‘Hitler's Atomic Bomb’ needs to be corrected" (http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/bewi.201601794/abstract) shows that the German physicist did not know how to build a nuclear bomb.

Answer (score 4):

During WW2 the Germans were also working on a transatlantic cruise missile using a mixture of coal dust, diesel and Acetone.

[image: Lorin Ramjet tests early 1942]

Tests were performed with such ramjet engines atop a Dornier 217 aircraft in France through the war.

[image: Lorin ramjet]

Trommsdorff-D-6000-Interkontinentalflugkörper was intended to launch from high altitude bombers such as the He-277 at altitudes of 46,000ft and 0.67 Mach. After launch they would climb to 80,000ft flying at 2.8 Mach much like the SR-71 cruise altitude. They would continue their flights to USA as robots similar in concept to the V-1.

[image: Trommsdorff D-6000]

Source:

"The V2 & the German, Russian and American Rocket Program"p.89, by Claus Reuter

Answer (score 3):

One German super weapon that didn't quite make it was the [Type XXI Electro-Boat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_XXI_submarine)

It's high underwater speed and endurance meant it could move faster than surface ships could hunt it.

However, the XXI was plagued with development difficulties, and only one made it to an actual war patrol, in the last week of the war.

The design was so advanced that the Soviets used it as the basis for their Whiskey class diesel-electric submarines, and the XXI hull design was used for the first nuclear sub, the USS Nautilus.

But, even that had problems. Dr John Craven was tasked with studying the Nautilus, and reports in his book The Silent War, that it had serious cavitation problems with its ballast tanks when traveling at speed under water, so much so that the cavitation was tearing the outer hull apart. The USN was able to solve that problem, and eventually went to a teardrop shape that was even more efficient than the XXI design.

Would the XXI have reversed the battle of the Atlantic, had it been available in sufficient numbers? Probably not. Late in the war, the Allies were relying more on aircraft launched from baby carriers and the FIDO homing torpedo to attack German submarines. As fast as the XXI was, it wasn't faster than an aircraft or a torpedo. The XXI would have caused problems for a few months before they would have been countered by new Allied tactics.

In the end, the super weapons had little effect on the outcome of the war, and probably were a drawback, as they consumed resources out of proportion to the results they returned.

WW2 was essentially a war of attrition and supply, one that the US and USSR, with their vast resources of materials and people, would inevitably win.

Answer (score -1):

**Nazi Germany developed tactical nuclear weapons as early as June 1942**

This was detailed in a Magic decrypt held in NSA archives known as "Stockholm to Tokyo, No. 232.9 December 1944 (War Department), RG 457,  declassified October 1, 1978. It was sent by the Japanese embassy in Stockholm decrypted on 12 December 1944. It refers to German development of a 5 kilogram nuclear warhead.

This signal states in part that:

> **The German atom-splitting device is the Neuman disintegrator. Enormous energy is directed into the central part of the atom and this generates an atomic pressure of several tens of thousands of tons per square inch. This device can split the relatively unstable atoms of such elements as uranium. Moreover, it brings into being a store of explosive atomic energy.... That is, a bomb deriving its force from the release of atomic energy.**

[image: cover page]

[image: P1]

[image: P2]

[image: P3]

[image: P4]

[image: p5]

In another document prepared at the end of the war from interrogations of interned combatants by the US Naval Technical Mission Europe, cited as: “Investigations, Research, Developments and Practical Use of the German Atomic Bomb” dated 19 August 1945.

In that document there was an affidavit actually written by an interpreter Captain Helenes T Freiberger of the testimony given under interrogation by pilot observer Hauptman Hans Zinsser who said:

> **At the beginning of October 1944, I flew from Ludwigslust (south of Luebeck) [to] about 12 to 15 km from an atomic bomb test station, when I noticed a strong, bright illumination of the whole atmosphere, lasting about 2 seconds.**
>
> **The clearly visible pressure wave escaped the approaching and following cloud formed by the explosion. This wave had a diameter of about 1 km when it became visible and the colour of the cloud changed frequently. It became dotted after a short period of darkness with all sorts of light spots, which were, in contrast to normal explosions, of a pale blue colour.**
>
> **After about ten seconds the sharp outlines of the explosion disappeared, then the cloud began to take on a lighter colour, against the sky covered with a grey overcast. The diameter of the still visible pressure wave was at least 9000 metres (9km) while remaining visible for at least 15 seconds.**
>
> **Personal observations of the colours of the explosion cloud found an almost blue-violet shade. During this manifestation reddish-coloured rims were to be seen, changing to a dirty-like shade in very rapid succession.**
>
> **The combustion was lightly felt from my observation plane in the form of pulling and pushing. The appearance of atmospheric disturbance lasted about ten seconds, without perceivable climax.**
>
> **About an hour later I started with an He-111 (aircraft) from the A/D at Ludwigslust and flew in an easterly direction. Shortly after the start I passed through almost complete overcast (between 3,000 and 4,000 meter altitude). A cloud shaped like a mushroom with turbulent billowing sections (at about 7,000 meter altitude) stood, without any seeming connections, over the spot where the explosion took place. Strong electrical disturbances and the impossibility to continue radio communication as by lightning, turned up.**

[image: Zinsser]

There is further corroboration by a USN Intelligence report dated June 15, 1945 concerning "German Technology Transfer to Japan"

In Chapter 14 of that document it states this:

[image: excerpt transfer of Atomic weapons to Japan]

The German scientists behind this 5kg warhead were Haxel, Schumann & Trinks. What they developed was a method for detonating sub critical fissile mass by a process known as Fusion boosted Fission. It uses the plasma Pinch concept to ignite a mass of uranium far below the critical mass by using nuclear fusion to replicate the neutron flux required in a fissile mass at criticality.

[image: Schumann Trinks warhead]

In order to create fusion two opposing Hollow charges with conical Lithium liners were fired at a small mass of Uranium coated with Lithium-Deuteride plus a 2% contamination of Boron to slow down the reaction.

When conventional chemical explosive charges smashed the molten lithium liners into the Deuteride nuclear fusion occurred, expressing a vast nuclear flux. This worked like a spark plug to ignite the Uranium.

Maj General Dornberger leader of the V-2 project was interned in a special camp after the war for senior staff officers where all the rooms were bugged with hidden microphones. Transcript summaries of his conversations between 2-7 August 1945 were used in evidence at Nuremberg. Although heavily censored after the trials the report suggests Germany planned to use 5kg tactical nuclear weapons on the V-2 and also on the Rheinbote missile (mounted on an 88mm gun)

[image: Rheinbote]

Comment: just as interesting, they describe a hollow pit design, which the US introduced into their weapons only several years after the war, mainly because of manufacturing problems.

Comment: Popp 2016: "Misinterpreted Documents and Ignored Physical Facts: The History of ‘Hitler's Atomic Bomb’ needs to be corrected" (http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/bewi.201601794/abstract) shows that the German physicist did not know how to build a nuclear bomb.

Comment: The second picture reads, quote, "It is a fact that in June of 1942 the German Army tried out an utterly new type of weapon against the Russians at a location 150 kilometers southeast of Kursk. Althrough it was the entire 19th Infantry Regiment of the Russians which was thus attacked, only a few bombs (each round up to 5 kilograms) sufficed to utterly wipe them out to the last man." -- This gets a very weak smile from me. "A few" 5 kg (!!) tac-nukes, operational by 1942 and then never heard of again, when they failed to get a chain reaction even at Haigerloch?

Answer (score -3):

According to a wartime report held on microfilm file at Maxwell AFB, Alabama, S.R.A.4394, the US 9th Army captured a working German Atomic bomb on 26 April 1945 near Goslar. The device known as 76-Zentner weighed 3.8 tons and the document notes it was flown back to the United States by Col Charles Lindbergh who in addition to being a qualified B-24 pilot was also a consultant to the US Navy Technical Mission Europe.

During 1945 Allied advances overran underground factories housing at least 60+ Anschutz Mark IIIB Uranium centrifuges each capable of enriching 250grams of Uranium by 7% per 24 hours. During each 12 day cycle these could produce 15kg of HEU enriched to 80% U235. At this rate Germany was capable during the second half of 1944 of producing enough HEU for one Hiroshima type bomb every 7 weeks.

Sources;

NARA G-344 (9 Apr. 1946) Jesse W. Beams, "Report on the use of the centrifuge method for the concentration of U235 by the Germans."

Correspondence with Dirk Finkemeier and Keith Sanders about Underground nuclear factory at Espekamp captured 4th April 1945

March 1946 interrogation of Konrad Beyerle, Chief Engineer Anschutz & Co.

Comment: unsourced conspiracy theories aren't viable answers.

Comment: While this "information" is certainly unconventional, I disagree that it is a "conspiracy theory". The poster is citing facts, if you think the facts are fabricated, fine, downvote the answer. As long as the poster is citing (remotely) plausible facts, I think it qualifies as an answer. The "conspiracy theory" restriction, in my interpretation is aimed at people who spin up factless theories that are unverifiable. We want to error on the side of inclusiveness, even if sometimes it results in some kooky answers.

Comment: The claim here is extraordinary (to be generous), and the only (supposed) reference provided is quite conveniently off-line and not available to the public.

Comment: @T.E.D. No question about that, but he is citing theoretically verifiable facts. Also, it is an answer, not a question. Nowhere in the Help does it say you can't give wacky answers. If he were asking a question, sure, he would be held to a higher standard, but for an answer maybe he deserves the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @TylerDurden - I didn't say it wasn't an answer. I'm just explaining why I downvoted.

Comment: @TED the fact an authentic archived source is not published online does not disqualify it, or dismiss it's claims. That is just a lazy excuse you're parading to dismiss something you can't explain or discount, but desperately don't want to believe.

Comment: @jwenting I challenge you to disprove the sources cited

Comment: "I challenge you to disprove" is a standard Conspiracy Theory line of rhetoric. The burden of proof is on the one making the claim.  See also this point made by Dev Solar ... "A few" 5 kg (!!) tac-nukes, operational by 1942 and then never heard of again, when they failed to get a chain reaction even at Haigerloch?" Occam's Razor has cut you again.